# uitapgesturerecognizer does not work on subviews iOS

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am having my mainViewController names as GameViewController with the following code:

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, GameDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *cardContainerView;


... (the following code is in a function called -DealCards)

for (PlayerPosition p = startingPlayer.position; p < startingPlayer.position + 4; ++p)
{
    Player *player = [self.game playerAtPosition:p % 4];
    CardView *cardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CardWidth, CardHeight)];
    cardView.card = [player.closedCards cardAtIndex:t];
    cardView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [self.cardContainerView addSubview:cardView];
    [cardView animateDealingToBottomPlayer:player withIndex:t withDelay:delay];
    delay += 0.1f;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardSelected:)];
    [recognizer setDelegate:self];
    [cardView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

The CardView is a subclass of UIView:

```
@implementation CardView
{
    UIImageView *_backImageView;
    UIImageView *_frontImageView;
    CGFloat _angle;
}

@synthesize card = _card;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self loadBack];
        self.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Because of limited space, the cards are placed one on top of the other, like the half card is visible and the rest is covered from the card on top and so on.

I want to be able to identify which card is pressed.

However, in my mainViewController I do have this function:

```
-(void)cardSelected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Card Selected with gestures");
}
```

but it is never called.

Can you help with what is missing? There might be some view that blocks the touches or something but I cannot figure out which one. I am confused by the fact that CardViews are added as a subView of `self.cardContainerView` which is a property of my GameViewController.

Comment: You set `self.cardContainerView.userInteractionEnabled=YES`, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GameViewController` you add this :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.cardContainerView];
    CardView *selectedCard;
    for (CardView *card in self.cardContainerView.subviews)
    {
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(card.frame, touchLocation))
     {
         selectedCard = card;

     }
    }

    NSLog(@"Value %d",selectedCard.card.value);
}
```

Of course you eliminate the values with 0 and the rest are the cards.

I haven't placed a `break;` there because some of the views are overlapping and it will get the first one instead of the one above, of course you could iterate backwards and fix that if you want.

Comment: Yes but then I would have to find out which card was clicked based on its position which is not that easy, i think. Or can I do it differently, like using a tag or something else? Can you edit your code with an example of how to identify which card was clicked?

Comment: You could send a NSNotification , I'll edit my post to show you.

Comment: Check it out and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I am getting this :
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GameViewController _movedToFront]: unrecognized selector

Comment: Have you placed the -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 inside the CardView class?

Comment: Ok I did that, but it seems that the touch is not recognised again. I have place a simple NSLog inside the touchesBegan and it is not shown. If the touchesBegan is placed inside the maiViewController without the NSNotification, then I can see the log but I do not know which card has been clicked.

Comment: Remove the UITapGestureRecognizer form your code, because the touches are automatically enabled, it should work, and the only thing that keeps them out is the gesture.

Comment: yes I have removed them. Have you seen this: If the touchesBegan is placed inside the maiViewController without the NSNotification, then I can see the log but I do not know which card has been clicked.

Comment: your interest is to select the card, so this isn't used for the viewcontroller that's why i told you to place it inside the CardView because I'm referencing the CardView to the parent.

Comment: and so I did but it is not called. I can not see the NSLog. Whatever card I click, nothing is printed. I tried for testing to place that touchesBegan in the mainView and then it is shown wherever I click on screen but this is not what i want either. Therefore, if I place it in the cardView it is like, touches are not identified at all. Maybe some view is blocking me or something else.

Comment: check your methods to see if aren't disabling userInteraction because it should automatically work upon subclassing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! One final question. I have my mainViewController, inside it a UIView called cardContainer and inside that all the subviews of CardViews (which inside has ImageViews). Which of them should have interactionEnabled and which of them disabled?

Comment: So, from the start the UIImageView's user interaction is disabled by default, and if that is an subview of CardView then all the touches go to the CardView, even if it has userInteraction enabled , so don't worry about subviews of CardView,you should check and see if cardContainer has userInteraction enabled and as far as i saw every CardView has userInteraction enabled so that's ok. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Could you send the project so I can check it out?, or at least a demo of it, I don't need it all.

Comment: sure no problem. How can I do it from here or send you an email?

Comment: use transfer.ro to upload the archive of the project and post the link downhere.

Comment: Ok, i'll see what is going on.

Comment: Ok , i figured out what to do, the subviews aren't working but i did it inside the GameViewController, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You can remove everything else i said , with this code it will select the card.

Comment: It works! You are great!! Thanks for the time you spent on that!

Comment: No problem, make sure you'll let me know when you finish the game so we can have a match.